# Delete duplicates and sort tab by dates in Python

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, tabs

I receive as input a table in which there will be two data per line, a date and an associated value. I am looking for one or more methods that could filter the table to remove the rows that exist in several times and then arrange the rows according to the date. 
My tab looks like this:

```
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=34781, microseconds=474000), 0.004936)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=33586, microseconds=443000), 0.003214)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=34781, microseconds=474000), 0.004936)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=38306, microseconds=654000), 0.001765)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=38306, microseconds=654000), 0.001765)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=31245, microseconds=474000), 0.004938)
...
```

Until now I tried to use

```
import datetime

listData = [(datetime.timedelta(seconds=34781, microseconds=474000), 0.004936),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=33586, microseconds=443000), 0.003214),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=34781, microseconds=474000), 0.004936),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=38306, microseconds=654000), 0.001765),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=38306, microseconds=654000), 0.001765),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=31245, microseconds=474000), 0.004938)]

finalTab = []
for i in listData:
   if i not in finalTab: finalTab.append(i)

print(finalTab)
```

But this method would just manage half of the issue and it would takes too much time I think, I have to process files of this format of several gigabytes (~ 21 600 000 lines).

I need to something like this as output:

```
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=31245, microseconds=474000), 0.004938)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=33586, microseconds=443000), 0.003214)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=34781, microseconds=474000), 0.004936)
(datetime.timedelta(seconds=38306, microseconds=654000), 0.001765)
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It s not exactly clear what you want but you could put all dates in a _set_ to remove duplicates and then recover the 2nd value of the tuple with a iteration (don't know about performance)

Comment: I have a tab in which I will have two data per line, a date associated with a value. I receive as input the first table presented, the rows are not arranged in the correct order and there may be duplicates (a row appears several times with the date and its value).
What I'm trying to do is first delete the lines that exist in several times and then arrange the tab according to date and time.

Comment: I tried to set dates inside a new tab if it doesn't already exist but it takes a of time (for a test file of 450 000 lines it wasn't done after 40 minutes.

Comment: List lookup is pretty slow. Making a set out of `listData` would unify the items: `finalTab = set(listData)`. With sorting you could try: `finalTab = sorted(set(listData), key=lambda t: t[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually quite simple, thanks to Timus this code answer the question :

```
import datetime

listData = [(datetime.timedelta(seconds=34781, microseconds=474000), 0.004936),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=33586, microseconds=443000), 0.003214),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=34781, microseconds=474000), 0.004936),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=38306, microseconds=654000), 0.001765),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=38306, microseconds=654000), 0.001765),
            (datetime.timedelta(seconds=31245, microseconds=474000), 0.004938)]

finalTab = sorted(set(listData), key=lambda t: t[0])

print(finalTab)
```